# Why does CluePedia-v1.5.9-2 fail to work with Cytoscape-v3.10?

Tags: new-operator, cytoscape, incompatibility

I have updated to Cytoscape-v3.10 and I have noticed that CluePedia-v1.5.9-2 does not work anymore with ClueGO-v2.5.9, despite the fact that I have installed both ClueGO and CluePedia apps in my computer.

Is there any incompatibility between Cytoscape-v3.10 and CluePedia-v1.5.9-2?

I have not such a problem with the previous version of Cytoscape (v3.9.1), which is installed in the same computer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is an incompatibility between Cytoscape 3.10.0 and the latest version of the CluePedia App. You will likely need to wait for the release of Cytoscape 3.10.1 for a fix. In the meantime the only workaround is to keep using Cytoscape 3.9.1.

Comment: Thank you for the information. Yes, I have been using CluePedia v1.5.3 wihin Cytoscape v3.9.1 with no problem.